# Tab with Gmail account spontaneously switches to primary email

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have two Gmail accounts, one as @gmail.com, one under a different domain that is my primary account. Frequently, I have two tabs open in the browser, one for each. The gmail.com tab will spontaneously switch to the primary email, so that both tabs show the same thing, after what seems like some kind of timeout period of inactivity. This behavior started a few weeks ago and is very consistent; prior to that, I've had no trouble since Google introduced multiple email support.

How do I restore the previous behavior of keeping the same email in each tab?

Comment: After this was posted, I was composing a reply and it switched in _the middle of typing_, so it is definitely not a timeout. Fortunately Google had saved the draft.

Answer (score 4):

At a job I had a few years ago, I had a similar problem. I addressed the issue by opening one in Firefox and the other in Chrome.

Using different browser applications prevented the two instances from cross communicating.

Comment: Or, open an incognito/private browsing window for one of the accounts.

Comment: Or, better, user profiles in Chrome. No need for incognito mode.